# Add key/value pair to object within array of arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

Given the following structure:

```
const data = {
  "show": "Family Guy",
  "characters": [
      [{name: 'Peter', age: 40, city: 'Quahog'}],
      [{name: 'Louis', age: 30}],
      [{name: 'Chris', age: 16}],
      [{name: 'Stewie', age: 1}]
    ]
 }
```

How can we add to each character the key/value pair of `city: 'Quahog'` so the output looks as follows:

```
const item = {
  "show": "Family Guy",
  "characters": [
      [{name: 'Peter', age: 40, city: 'Quahog'}],
      [{name: 'Louis', age: 30, city: 'Quahog'}], // city added
      [{name: 'Chris', age: 16, city: 'Quahog'}], // city added
      [{name: 'Stewie', age: 1, city: 'Quahog'}]  // city added
    ]
 }
```

We tried using:

```
let city = data.characters.[0][0].city;
costs = _.map(items, (itemArray) => {
            items = _.map(itemArray, (item) => {
              if(!item.city) {
                item.city = city;
              }
        });
```

But it's not working as intended and we can't get the desired output. Any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way of doing it with `.reduce()`:

```js
const data = {
  "show": "Family Guy",
  "characters": [
  [{name: 'Peter', age: 40, city: 'Quahog'}],
  [{name: 'Louis', age: 30}],
  [{name: 'Chris', age: 16}],
  [{name: 'Stewie', age: 1}]
]
 };

data.characters.reduce((a,c)=>
 (c[0].city=a[0].city,a));

console.log(data);
```

When using `.reduce()` without a second argument it will pick up the first array element as the initial value which is then used as a template to copy the `.city` property to all the other elements. The actual return value of the `.reduce()` method is discarded but the input array itself (`data`) is modified in the process and is then shown in the `console.log()` expression.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is the shortest and sweetest way to do it. In your desc, did you mean *with* a second argument? Also, in the return does the *,a* part just write the modified result back to a, or does it do something else? Thanks again

Comment: Well, the callback function is the _first_ argument of the `.reduce()` method (the callback function in turn has two arguments). But the missing _second_ argument to the `.reduce()` method would have been a starting value, which is missing on purpose here.

Comment: The `,a` part in the callback makes sure that the accumulator (in this case: the first array element) is handed along to the next iteration. Without it the `.reduce()` call would fail.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the reason for having these single item arrays but this solution will do the work (I'll recommend you take a look at the process that creates this data format which is a little weird)

```js
const data = {
  "show": "Family Guy",
  "characters": [
      [{name: 'Peter', age: 40, city: 'Quahog'}],
      [{name: 'Louis', age: 30}],
      [{name: 'Chris', age: 16}],
      [{name: 'Stewie', age: 1}]
    ]
 }
 
 const city = data.characters.find(characters => characters.find(character => character.city))[0].city

const dataWithCities = {
 ...data,
 characters: data.characters.map(characters => characters.map(character => character.city ? character : {...character, city}))
 }
 
 console.log(dataWithCities)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
let city = data.characters.[0][0].city;
let newdata = [];
data.characters.map(items, (itemArray) => {
        items = _.map(itemArray, (item) => {
          if(item.city === undefined) {
              newdata.push({...item , city});
          } else { 
           newdata.push({...item});
           }

    })
    costs = {...newdata}
```

Comment: Please add supporting details to your answer to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without lodash

```
const data = {
  "show": "Family Guy",
  "characters": [
      [{name: 'Peter', age: 40, city: 'Quahog'}],
      [{name: 'Louis', age: 30}],
      [{name: 'Chris', age: 16}],
      [{name: 'Stewie', age: 1}]
    ]
 }

const chars = data.characters.map((x)=>{

    return {...x[0] , city : x[0].city ? x[0].city : city} 
})

const items = {...data , characters : chars};
```

Comment: hmm this doesn't wrap each character in an array, it's just a group of object

Answer (score 0):

```
const { city } = data.characters.find(([item]) => !!item.city?.length)[0];

const newData = {
    ...data,
    characters: data.characters.map(([char]) => [{ ...char, city }])
};
```